# Xcode crashes after launching

Tags: iphone, osx-lion

i have installed xcode latest version on lion running in vmware, but after installation when i launch xcode, it crashes with the following crash log.

ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-1938/Framework/Utilities/IBFoundationAdditions.m:141
Details:  Assertion failed: originalMethod != ((void*)0)
Function: void IBMethodSwizzle(Class, SEL, SEL)
Thread:   {name = (null), num = 1}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x0000000107fe75a1 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x0000000107641774 _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x00000001076531a4 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x000000010ad94152 IBMethodSwizzle (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  4  0x000000010b29b836 -[IBCocoaPlugin init] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration)
  5  0x000000010b29afbb +[IBCocoaPlugin ide_initializeWithOptions:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration)
  6  0x0000000107b608bc _IDEInitializeOnePlugInAndPrerequisites (in IDEFoundation)
  7  0x0000000107b6060d *IDEInitializeOnePlugInAndPrerequisites (in IDEFoundation)
  8  0x0000000107b600cc IDEInitialize (in IDEFoundation)
  9  0x0000000107ee2c18 -[IDEApplicationController applicationWillFinishLaunching:] (in IDEKit)
 10  0x00007fff8c672216 _*-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_1 (in Foundation)
 11  0x00007fff898792aa _CFXNotificationPost (in CoreFoundation)
 12  0x00007fff8c57117b -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] (in Foundation)
 13  0x00007fff9135b819 -[NSApplication finishLaunching] (in AppKit)
 14  0x00007fff9135b3e5 -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 15  0x00007fff9135433d NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 16  0x00000001075e8eec (in Xcode)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Lion Gold Master or Lion Retail?  Apparently Xcode only works with Lion Retail.